# cordova-plugin-googlemaps in vuejs doesn't show

Tags: cordova, vuejs2, cordova-plugins, phonegap, html-framework-7

Fellows,

I am trying to make a Phonegap/Cordova (and Framework7) with cordova-plugin-googlemaps to work with Vuejs. Despite everything seems ok, the map is not loaded.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
    <f7-page name="mapa">
        <div id="mapcanvas"></div>
    </f7-page>
</template>

<script>
  var map;
  let deviceReady = false;
  let vueMounted = false;
  export default {
    name: 'Mapa',
    data() {
      return {
        isConnected: false,
        map: undefined
      }
    },
    created () {
      vueMounted = true;
      if (deviceReady) this.everythingReady();
    },
    methods: {
      everythingReady() {
        var div = document.getElementById("mapcanvas");

        map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);

        map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, this.onMapReady);
      },
      onMapReady(){
        alert("mapa pronto");
      },
      onButtonClick() {
        map.animateCamera({
          target: {lat: 37.422359, lng: -122.084344},
          zoom: 17,
          tilt: 60,
          bearing: 140,
          duration: 5000
        }, function() {

          map.addMarker({
            position: {lat: 37.422359, lng: -122.084344},
            title: "Welecome to \n" +
            "Cordova GoogleMaps plugin for iOS and Android",
            snippet: "This plugin is awesome!",
            animation: plugin.google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
          }, function(marker) {

            marker.showInfoWindow()

            marker.on(plugin.google.maps.event.INFO_CLICK, function() {

              alert("Hello world!")

            });
          });
        });
      },
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener('deviceReady', () => {
    deviceReady = true
    if (vueMounted) this.everythingReady()
  }, false);

</script>

<style>
    #mapcanvas{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        position:absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    canvas{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

The method onMapReady() is been executed, but the map is not been printed.

UPDATE:
I changed a little bit the code to make sure the code is executed after the Vuejs module is created, and the deviceready listener is also fired. But had no success!

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is map_canvas set in CSS to have dimensions? (e.g. 100vw, 100vh)

Comment: It wasn't set, but now it is. Still can't see the map!

Comment: One more thing to look at - I know Google Maps uses <canvas> under the hood - is there anything in your css which talks to the canvas tag? e.g. canvas {display:none}

Comment: There is nothing like that. I am running a test after including: canvas{display: block;}. It didn't work!

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with Vue and the template render - is the template definitely rendered before the code triggers? Usually when I create a Vue template it is with var vm = new Vue(...)

Comment: Code updated, but no success! Do you have a working code with this kind of configuration?

Comment: Nope - I use Vue in a more basic fashion with existing Dom elements, like e.g. <div id="app">
   <p>{{ message }}</p>
 </div>

Comment: then: new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
   }
 })

Comment: You seem to have a <template> tag and some "export" syntax. I did notice you have "mapa"and "Mapa" - maybe its case sensitive?

Comment: It seems that the problem is related to Framework7. But I cant figure it out what it is.

Comment: There is an interesting bit of code on line 28081 of framework7.js in a function loadSdk(),  script.src = 'http://c.vi-serve.com/viadshtml/vi.min.js'; This kind of thing really puts me off "black box" frameworks - so hard to debug or understand your dependancies! ( or even know if something malicious is going on ). Maybe try doing your app without it?

Comment: Yes my friend! Indeed! I am considering not using it. I check other ways to acomplish what I need. Thank your for your advice.

Comment: Cool! Good Luck! The other thing you need to ensure is that you are not including Google maps JS locally. e.g. do this: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.7&sensor=true"></script> , not this: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myLocalCopy/GoogleMaps3.7.js"></script>

Comment: I am going into IONIC4 and QUASAR. I like what I see!! I hope F4's version2 gets better!! Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the everythingReady function, you can not access the elment `mapcanvas` because it does not yet exist, you have to wait until Vue has mounted the HTML code of your template.

You can check the life cycle of Vue;

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Specifically, you must implement the `mounted`  method, it should look something like:

```
//...
mounted () {
  if (deviceReady) {
     this.everythingReady();
 
},
//...
```

You can guide yourself from this manual which I find useful:

- https://medium.com/founders-factory/building-a-custom-google-map-component-with-vue-js-d1c01ddd0b0a